# Angular Reactive Form control with type=number will re-render on blur

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular(v7) Reactive Form (might be same for template-only form).
An `<input>` with `type="number"` will re-render and run validation on blur.
There is a value suggestion button in the error feedback `<div>` next to the `<input>`, and clicking the button will fill the input with the suggested value (provided by an async validator).
However, if you click the button the first time, the blur of the `<input>` will trigger re-rendering of the whole element, thus having no effect of the input. You have to click the button a second time to make it work.

I didn't find any option to disable this re-rendering behaviour.

Demo: [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5ih9j)

.ts File:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newPlanForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      plan_id: [
        {
          value: this.plan.plan_id,
          disabled: !this.plan.insurer_id,
        }, {
          validators: [Validators.required, this.planIdSyntaxValidator.bind(this)],
          asyncValidators: this.planIdDuplicationValidator.bind(this),
          // updateOn: 'blur' // this is my hacky solution. The original problem occours without it
        }
      ],
      ...
    });
}

planIdDuplicationValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    // duplication check
    ...
}

fillInSuggestedPlanId(): void {
    this.form.plan_id.setValue(this.form.plan_id.errors.duplicatePlanId);
}

// convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get form() {
    return this.newPlanForm.controls;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="newPlanForm">
    ...
    <label for="plan_id">Plan ID<sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="plan_id" name="plan_id"
           [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': form.plan_id.errors }"
           formControlName="plan_id"/>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form.plan_id.dirty && form.plan_id.errors">
      <p *ngIf="form.plan_id.errors.duplicatePlanId">
        This plan ID is already taken. Next available is
        <a (click)="fillInSuggestedPlanId()" class="btn-link">
          {{suggestedPlanID}}
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Try removing updateOn:'blur' property from your validators array

Comment: @Chellappan Sorry it was my hacky solution, actually the problem occurs without it. (BTW it is a config attribute of the control itself, not at validator level.) See my edit.

Comment: Please create a demo displaying this issue :)

Comment: @AJT_82 added demo. Please input anything except "12345" and click the link button below and you will see the problematic behavior.

Comment: @MylesFong I will surely take a look at it. Just got to work though, so I guess I need to work :D Hopefully you can wait a bit and I will try my best to help you a bit later :)

Answer (score 1):

Please notice [the following note placed at the specs for input=number](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#when-number-is-not-appropriate) :

> Note: The type=number state is not appropriate for input that happens to only consist of numbers but isn't strictly speaking a number. For example, it would be inappropriate for credit card numbers or US postal codes. A simple way of determining whether to use type=number is to consider whether it would make sense for the input control to have a spinbox interface (e.g. with "up" and "down" arrows). Getting a credit card number wrong by 1 in the last digit isn't a minor mistake, it's as wrong as getting every digit incorrect. So it would not make sense for the user to select a credit card number using "up" and "down" buttons. When a spinbox interface is not appropriate, type=text is probably the right choice (possibly with a pattern attribute).

I have to ask: why not using just `type=text`?

Comment: Thank you and it makes sense for this case.  But what if there is another case that type=number is correct, like input for quantity, and requires a hint value button like in my case?